# get 10 birthdays including upcoming and passed with age count from mysql field of unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp, date

I cant figure out mysql query for it so i was thinking maybe someone can help me.

I have mysql table with users data including their birthday (inserted by php with time()) and i need to get 10 birthdays out of it. The tricky part is that it should get upcoming and passed birthdays with users age on bday. Upcoming would be within next day.
Like this:

- 13:44 01-03-2013 Bob became 10 years old
- 15:55 04-03-2013 Sara will be 22 years old

Person age is probably best to calculate with php after the query and i can do that on my own.

But if this query cant be done then i guess its okay to get 10 upcoming birthdays and 10 passed birthdays, this should be possible.

Thank you all for reading and helping!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: [Howto select upcoming birthdays](http://www.tsc-web.net/archive/2007/12/mysql-query-howto-select-upcoming-birthdays/comment-page-1/)